Multiple articulations, one sound
I've read a close duplicate, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not thinking of how we use one symbol to represent a range of values.
Recently someone told me they felt they were "faking" their second-language accent by "not really making the sounds right, just doing the right sounds wrong". As a fluent speaker of this language, I'd say that although their sounds are articulated in the most typical way 100% of the time, they're unusually good and I don't doubt based on their trajectory so far that they'll get there — perhaps not with the unthinking ease of a native speaker but the practiced accuracy of a news presenter.
However, it got me thinking. To what degree would it be possible to "fake" the sounds of a language while articulating them "wrong", to the point that your average fluent speaker without linguistic training would be fooled? The linked question mentions ventriloquism, which is an interesting direction.
At one extreme, it's obviously possible to create the correct sonic waveforms without the articulators; this is the whole principle behind recorded and synthesized speech. My question is specifically: given the articulators we have as humans, are we pretty limited in our options for "alternative means" to the same perceptual end? If research has been done on this question, what leads would you suggest?

Luke, I'm going to remove all my comments but before I do, that reference to your speaker in the second paragraph doesn't make sense to me: faking it "by doing the right sounds wrong". What the person feels and how they sound can be two different things. Anyway, I still do not get your idea. Sorry. I don't want to be a pain, but it's quite difficult to understand.

@Lambie Fair enough. The question is my best attempt to interpret their meaning, and maybe the anecdote is irrelevant... I'll think about what I'm trying to ask and how to ask it more clearly.

The more I scratch my head here, the more I can only come up with accents. The articulatory apparatus is accessed differently by different accents but it's still language A or B. If you do the right sounds in the wrong way, (un rat, a rat), the r in the back versus in the front when saying a rat in English, it's still English right? (The Israelis can't get that r, they push it back).
